# How to catch 401 response in Laravel/Lumen?

Tags: php, laravel, api, lumen

I am writing an api for authorize users .

With my current code I can catch if response code is **200** however 
I cannot catch if the response is 401 instead of 200. Instead of an error message with my 401 response, I recieve error page.

this is my swagger server in Lumen

```
if($input['phone']==$this->phone && $input['password'] == $this->password){
            return response()->json([
            'redirect_uri' => $redirect_uri,
            'token' => $this->token 
            ]); 
        }

        return response()->json([
            'redirect_uri' => $redirect_uri,
            'errorMsg' => 'User Not found or id psw wrong'
            ],401);
```

and this is my model in Laravel

```
if($response->getStatusCode() == 401){
            dd('you are not authorized');
        }

        if($response->getStatusCode() == 200){
            dd('you are authorized');
           //Store user credentials on cache
            CacheStore::storeUserCredentials(json_decode((string) $response->getBody(), true));
        }
```

basically if statuscode is 200 I recieve this message

[image]

But if status code is 401 it gives error.

[image]

Comment: How do you call the API?

Answer (score 1):

Apply try catch block to your code

```
try{
  // your api call
}
catch(Exception $e)
{
    if ($e instanceof HttpException && $e->getStatusCode()== 401)
    {
      dd('you are not authorized');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend handling universal exceptions in `app\Exceptions\Handler.php`.
In this file, there exists a `render` function.

To deal with different types of Exception, you can try:

```
public function render($request, Exception $e)
{
    if ($e instanceof SomeTypeException1)
    {
        #handle it
    }
    else if($e instanceof SomeTypeException2)
    {
        #handle it
    }

    return parent::render($request, $e);
}
```